# Show text by pressing enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to show text on webpage by pressing enter may be in javascript/ jquery?

I want that if somebody opens the page and press enter than the text start appearing line by line like when we install something on linux through terminal the text appears line by line telling whats happening I want that type of animation? On webpage with static / plain text lines

Thanks

It's Not a progress bar I want simple animation like terminal in which each line of plane text come one after the other

For example I have opened the webpage and I press enter than the text start appearing like terminal. Line by line

sample code

```
<html>
<head>

<head>
  <body>
    <h1>PLease press enter</h1>
    <span id="line-1" class="hidden">some text here</span>
    <span id="line-2" class="hidden">some text here</span>
    <span id="line-3" class="hidden">some text here</span>
    <span id="line-4" class="hidden">some text here</span>
    <span id="line-5" class="hidden">some text here</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Important NOTE**
I have no idea of jQuery and javascript

**EDITED**
Where I am wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
    <title>Testn</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <script>
      $(document).bind("keypress", function (e) {
        var t = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
        if (t == 13) {
          if ($("#span1").is(":visible") == false) $("#span1").show();
          else if ($("#span2").is(":visible") == false) $("#span2").show();)
          else if ($("#span3").is(":visible") == false) $("#span3").show();)
          else if ($("#span4").is(":visible") == false) $("#span4").show();)
          else $("#span5").show();)
       }
    </script>
    <span id="span1" >some text here</span>
    <span id="span2">some text here</span>
    <span id="span3" >some text here</span>
    <span id="span4" >some text here</span>
    <span id="span5">some text here</span>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried? This can be done with a keydown/keuyp event on the document itself.

Comment: Look for "jquery typewriter effect" and remember this: `var isEnter = e.which == 13`. With a bit of work you'll figure it out.

Comment: dont know what you actually want,but generally this is how you catch enter event: $(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        //do what you want after user hit enter
    }
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use jquery `on`..

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.

**updated**

```
$(function(){

  var $span=$('span');
  $span.hide();  // hide all soans in the document 
  var count= 1;
  $(document).on("keyup", function (e) {
   if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    if(count <= $span.length){
      $('#'+count).show();
      count++;
    }
  }
  });
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/GnyUA/)

Comment: is it possible to show all lines on one enter?

Comment: yes ...http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/GnyUA/1/..try this

Comment: yes its good but i want that each line shows after the other not all at once may be with time difference of 1 sec